# LibGDX - Rounded shaped texture

Tags: opengl, libgdx, textures, rounded-corners

I was wondering if it possible to give a shape to a Texture in LibGDX.

In particular, I have a Texture and I want to make a button out of it. To do so, I wanted to give it a rounded corners shape.

In a nutshell, I have this :

[image]

and I want this :

[image]

I've already read some similar questions with any clear answer. Does anyone have experience this problem and found a smart solution ?

Comment: A Texture is always a rectangle, but you can put transparency in the source image (alpha channel) and draw it with blending enabled (in the SpriteBatch) to get the effect you're describing. I think this is so basic that it's taken for granted that everyone knows this, so it's never mentioned in any documentation or tutorials.

Comment: I know it of course -.-

Comment: I was wondering if I could do this dynamically ! Because I need the rectangular Image for other users but I need it rounded to for the menu

Comment: So a [9-patch](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch)?

Comment: You can draw it with blending disabled to draw the full rectangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create rounded texture image using bellow method and then add text to it.

```
public static Texture createPixmapRoundCornerRect(Color color, int width,
            int height, int radius) {
        Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(width, height, Format.RGBA8888);
        pixmap.setColor(color);
        pixmap.fillCircle(radius, radius, radius);
        pixmap.fillCircle(width - radius, radius, radius);
        pixmap.fillCircle(width - radius, height - radius, radius);
        pixmap.fillCircle(radius, height - radius, radius);
        pixmap.fillRectangle(0, radius, width, height - (radius * 2));

        pixmap.fillRectangle(radius, 0, width - (radius * 2), height);
        Texture pixmaptex = new Texture(pixmap);
        pixmap.dispose();
        return pixmaptex;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5394546/2594807). You have to implement your own Texture which uses polygons to achieve what you are trying to do.